# How do you use SUMIF in Excel if the user filters the data?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My Access database generates an Excel worksheet that contains lines of detail and subtotals. My users also want a line at the bottom with the grand totals. I wrote a formula using the SUMIF function to leave out the lines that are already subtotals, but then if the user filters the data the line with the SUMIF doesn't change to reflect that. The I tried SUMPRODUCT but I can't get that to work, either. I've been going crazy Googling this everywhere, but not luck....

[image]

I want the cell circled in RED to reflect whatever the user may filter in columns B or C

So I tried this, but it ignores the filters

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(INDEX(H2:H721,1,1),ROW(H2:H721)-ROW(INDEX(H2:H721,1,1)),0))=1),--(D2:D721="SubTotal"),H2:H721)`

Any ideas?

*Thanks for any help!*

Comment: Check [Bill Jen's video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Zam8iv8TUc)

Comment: If this is "your" access database, why not pull in the data from Excel (into a pivottable) rather than pushing it from Access?

Comment: We built an Access database for the users to automate a bunch of other steps, and the user wants an Excel file as the output

Comment: Try changing the `,` to `*` between the criteria of the SUMPRODUCT: `=SUMPRODUCT((SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(INDEX(H2:H721,1,1),ROW(H2:H721)-ROW(INDEX(H2:H721,1,1)),0))=1)*(D2:D721="SubTotal")*H2:H721)`

Comment: Hi Scott....

I tried that (copied and pasted your sample formula, in fact) but the result is 0, not the sum

Comment: @BrianBattles Can you add a helper column? Or does it just need to be the single cell?

Comment: The users are asking for it to just have the cells shown, they have to send it along to some other group that needs it in a specific format...you know how these things can be!

Comment: @BrianBattles ... the subtotal(109... function mentioned in the 'Bill Jen's video' seems to answer your very question.. mind sharing what's the outcome?